# How to solve a PHP error in Laravel without changing the version?

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I have run into a problem when trying to upload my Laravel project to my live web server. Everything works perfectly on local server. But, my local server is running PHP 7.2.6, and my host server only supports 7.1 at this time. So, when I try to set up cron jobs for my server to run my Laravel scheduled tasks, I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/me/project/artisan on line 31

This line contains:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);
```

And I know the issue has to do with calling `Kernel::class`, but I am unable to change the PHP version to 7.2 to solve this. So, is there another workaround? My only worry is that even if I took care of this error, that there would be more.

Comment: that host seems to be using php < 5.5

Comment: I checked with `phpinfo()`, says I am using 7.1

Comment: that isn't the php configuration for the cli

Comment: I assume that you're using shared hosting. Even if shared hosting, you should able to change your php version at cpanel. Dİd you check it ?

Comment: What command did you use to set up your cronjob(s)? Do you have access to the command line?

Comment: Yes, I set it to use `7.1 edge`, which is supposed to be the lastest version of 7.1 they have available.

Comment: Here is the command for my cronjob `/usr/local/bin/php /home/me/project/artisan schedule:run 2>&1`

Comment: @RossWilson I do have command line access via ssh

Comment: If you run `/usr/local/bin/php -v` in the command line what version does it say?

Comment: you may want to try downgrade your laravel version to 5.5, it requires php 7.0 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5#server-requirements .. just delete composer.lock and vendor directory and change laravel version on composer.json and use  `composer install"`command

Comment: Ahhhhh that's it @RossWilson. The default version is 5.4. How would I point to 7.1?

Comment: Yes, CentOS Linux x86

Comment: Is it using cPanel or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that is how I set up the cronjobs

Comment: When I simply try `php` the same error comes up, and `/usr/local/bin/php71` doesn't exist

Comment: I don't have access to a cPanel box to test this sorry. If you run `ls /opt/cpanel | grep ea-` does it produce any results?

Comment: No, nothing comes up.

Comment: Do you have access to WHM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178231/discussion-between-hoolakoola-and-ross-wilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your getting seems to suggest you're using PHP <=5.4.

The default version of php used by the cli might not be the same version as the one being used for your site.

You can check this by running `php -v` on the command line to see which version it's using. If it is the wrong version then you should be able to run `whereis php` to get a list of paths to the different php versions available.

Once you've found the correct version then you can update your cronjob to use the path to the correct php executable e.g.

```
/path/to/php /home/username/path-to-artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```